# How do I add a string to a variable in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm creating a policy document for S3.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn,
      aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn+"/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

The 'resources' section requires a second ARN ending with /*

How do I achieve this? I've used +"/*" to illustrate the point.

I've been checking SO but I might not know the right term to search for because I'm getting irrelevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [iam_policy_document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html) examples.

You should be able to do the following string interpolation:

```
resources = [
    "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}",
    "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*"
]
```

Comment: That worked! I remember getting a warning at one point not to use the "${}" syntax for interpolation. I might be confusing it with something else though. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Glad it worked. This might be related with the newer Terraform versions. From the [upgrade notes](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-0-12-14-released/3898), quoting, "Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated: an expression like "${foo}" should be rewritten as just foo.". When you add the `/*`, I believe it's not an "Interpolation-only expression" anymore.

Comment: I see, that clears up that confusion. Thank you so much!